# What CMS is as close to "No-Code" as possible, allows custom fields and allows math type formulas to be applied?

Tags: database, content-management-system, customization

In the past I have used Zoho Creator which worked well but now I need something with a far better front end and something self hosted so I have been trying to find a CMS that can do what Creator does. I am currently using WP Toolset but is a nightmare to do the calculations I need it to. Have tried PRocesswire but no front end. Does anyone know of a CMS that is easy to "Fetch" data from other tables and fields and then return an answer? Or another idea altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I’m aware of a company who is doing just that. The app, delivery and all of it is in the cloud with management locked away multiple security U2F keys away form mere mortals. But the point is, this idea, to make it easier, backer resistant (never proof), and all that 1 it’s on the drawing hoard at some start ups. Not just one. Check into it. I wish I could give you more but I’m part of a team doing just that and it’s outside development that can caused either unseen bugs, too many classes or wrong type of classes, or otherwise screw with our once perfect baby.  So we are in essence sandboxinv all developers and forking their repo, even going a step further and giving them a dev repo that’s formed from our actual repo in real world terms.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.